# Install HP Laserjet 3015dn x86 drivers on X64 Win2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, 64-bit, printer, x86

I have a X64 Windows Server 2008 R2 which I installed my printer on. All X64 clients can without any problem install the printer on their machine, but not the X86 (WinXP) can.

I have tried to add X86 driver in the printer management console, but I cannot then add the aditionel X86 driver under "Sharing properties", when I point to the downloaded X86 folder from HP or from \DriverStore\FileRepostory.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Logged on to a Win7 X86 machine. Then connected to the Win2008 server via Print Management and pushed the X86 driver from Win7 to server.

Comment: Great, glad this worked for you. Be sure to mark this answer as "accepted" when you are able.